# The maths in "The Amazing Spider Man"

Tags: popular-math

I just saw the trailer for the new Spider Man movie and couldn't help but notice the image after the guy says "How did you come up with this". So here is a transcript (the last part can't be seen):

$$\eqalign{
  & \frac{{d\log \Phi }}{{dt}} = \alpha \left( {1 - g{{\left( {\frac{\Phi }{k}} \right)}^\beta }} \right)  \cr 
  & \Phi  = K\sum\limits_i {\prod\limits_j {\exp \left( {\frac{{{q^j}{{\left( {1 - {E_a}} \right)}^{j - 1}}}}{{\left( {j - 1} \right)!\left( {1 - {{\left( {1 - {E_a}} \right)}^{j - 1}}} \right)}}} \right)} } \log a \cdots  \cr} $$

[image]

Does it resemble, make sense, relate to any real math? (I dont really see any $i$ index inside the expression for example).
I actually laughed at the sigma, pi, exp triad.

Comment: Something tells me this may be a very popular question...

Comment: @David: retagged accordingly... ;)

Comment: On the other hand, the notation looks awfully like that of a [(thermodynamic) partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29), and thus this might be more appropriate as a question on physics.SE instead of here...

Comment: Then I'll post it there. Hope they don't mind the duplicate.

Comment: @Peter: It would be nice to post the link when you do that :) http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20734/the-maths-physics-in-the-amazing-spider-man.  As was pointed out there it is a duplicate of the physics.SE question [What does Peter Parkers formula represent?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/what-does-peter-parkers-formula-represent) from yesterday.

Comment: Over at Physics Stack Exchange they are wondering if some of those $1$'s might be $i$'s.